# simpleSAMLphp ADFS URLs

Tags: url, adfs, saml

I have a website that authenticates to ADFS using simpleSAMLphp. There are 4 web servers running RHEL 6 & Apache 2.2 behind a load-balancer. Call the 4 servers node1.mysite.com, node2.mysite.com, etc.. The users go to www.mysite.com (which points to the VIP) and are redirected to adfs.mysite.com to log in. After they login, they are redirected back to main website.

The problem is, when they are redirected back to the main web site, the URL contains the node they are on, like: node2.mysite.com, instead of www.mysite.com.

How can I configure simpleSAML (or ADFS) to redirect logged in users to www.mysite.com? I don't want to reconfigure apache to make this work if possible, tho I will if I have to (It's nice to have options).

I have a similar website setup that does work properly. The Apache configs all seem to match up. Meaning, the site that does not go to www after log on is setup the same way as the site that does go back to www after log on. Also, the site that does work, does not even have a .htaccess file.

I did not set this up and know very little about simpleSAMLphp or ADFS. I have searched the internet and have not found the answer. Maybe I don't know enuff about this to ask google correctly.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> authenticates to ADFS using simpleSAMLphp

Well, I don't understand what you mean by that, but it seems your website redirects to ADFS for authentication.

I would check the properties of the trust in the ADFS Management console. Locate your relying party (you should have only one for your site; not one by node) -> right-click -> Properties -> open the tab "Endpoints".

On this tab, the endpoint URLs have to point to www.mysite.com, not to nodeX.mysite.com.